# Jquery programming - src attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Facing issue in replacing "src" attribute.I am new to Jquery.Need to replace    `D:/Images/TaskList_1033_Button.png` by
`D:/Images/TaskList_1033_Button_Disabled.png`

```
<td>
    <div class=Editor>
        <span id=ctl02_G0_G22_G23_2_UserSelection_ECardButton_771_0_Editor class=Links disabled>
            <a style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: xx-small" id=ctl02_G0_G22_G23_2_UserSelection_ECardButton_771_0_Editor_0 hotKey="0">
                <img src="D:/Images/TaskList_1033_Button.png">
                <span></span>
                <input id=ctl02_G0_G22_G23_2_UserSelection_ECardButton_771_0_Editor_Selected_0 value=false type=hidden name=ctl02$G0$G22$G23$2_UserSelection_ECardButton_771_0$Editor$Selected_0>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

I used the below code for replacement but its not working
Script:

```
<div id="_vlv_script_">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
            var vObj = '';
            $("span[id*= _UserSelection_ECardButton]").attr("Disabled", "Disabled"); 
            vObj = $("span[id*= _UserSelection_PriorityActionButton]").children("a");
            vObj.attr(img[src]).replace("src",src.replace(.png", "_Disabled.png")); 
            $("span[id*= _UserSelection_ECardButton]").attr("Disabled", "Disabled"); 
            vObj = $("span[id*= _UserSelection_ECardButton]").children("a");
            vObj.attr(img[src]).replace("src",src.replace(.png", "_Disabled.png")); 
        }); 
    </script>
</div>
```

could you please help me??..Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code..

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code I found that you need to make following change.

You can try like this:

```
var currentSrc = vObj.find('img').attr('src');
currentSrc = currentSrc.replace(".png", "_Disabled.png");
vObj.find('img').attr('src', 'currentSrc');
```

Comment: I think you have mistakenly put single quotes for value of src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

your code have two little problem

```
 vObj.attr(img[src]).replace("src",src.replace(.png", "_Disabled.png"));
```

should be replaced with

```
 vObj.attr(img[src]).replace("src",src.replace(".png", "_Disabled.png"));
```

and

```
vObj.attr(img[src]).replace("src",src.replace(.png", "_Disabled.png"));
```

should be replaced with

```
vObj.attr(img[src]).replace("src",src.replace(".png", "_Disabled.png"));
```

then check again that problem persist or not